# grep files that contain a non commented text

Tags: grep

I need to find all files that contain MYSTRING which do not have a "#" before that.

for instance this one should return FALSE as there is an occurrence of "#" before MYSTRING in the same line:

```
a=1      #  otherstring  MYSTRING
```

and this one should return TRUE:

```
 # another line above is commented  but that's not on the same line
     a=1; MYSTRING
```

I have checked in the similar questions, but couldn't find exactly the same situation.

Comment: Or do 'grep -Ev "#.*MYSTRING" | grep MYSTRING'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
grep '^[^#]*MYSTRING' file.txt
```

- `^[^#]*MYSTRING` matches any number of characters from start that is not `#`, upto `MYSTRING` i.e. it matches lines that have `MYSTRING`, but no `#` anywhere before that on the line

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
 # another line above is commented  but that's not on the same line
     a=1; MYSTRING
a=1      #  otherstring  MYSTRING

% grep '^[^#]*MYSTRING' file.txt
     a=1; MYSTRING
```